# SSRS Line Chart Connecting two values in one line chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a line chart that contains 3 values (Previous Year Actual, Forecast and Current Year Actual) and a Category groups of (Month-Year ex: Jan-2016).  I am able to place the 3 values in a line chart fine, but I'm having a difficulty charting a "continuous line (with marker) " meaning first I'd like to chart the Current Year Actual Value and at the last month, for example, Feb-2016 the chart line for the Forecast will show.  I can do it in MSExcel, the line from the left is the actual and the highlighted in yellow is the forecast, but I unable to do it in SSRS. Please advise. [image: LineChart]

Answer (score 0):

Combine your data in your select query.  You can use a `UNION` statement like the below example.

```
SELECT actual_sales AS 'sales'
    , calendar_day AS 'calendar_day'
    , 'actual' AS 'sales_type'
FROM actual_sales_data
UNION
SELECT projected_sales AS 'sales'
    , calendar_day AS 'calendar_day'
    , 'projected' AS 'sales_type'
FROM projected_sales_data
```

Then you can chart both types of sales (actual and projected) in a continuous line because it will be one dataset.

Here is some sample data you can use with the example query:

```
DECLARE @actual_sales_data TABLE (actual_sales int, calendar_day DATE)
DECLARE @projected_sales_data TABLE (projected_sales int, calendar_day DATE)

INSERT INTO @actual_sales_data
SELECT 100, '1/1/2016'
UNION
SELECT 200, '1/2/2016'
UNION
SELECT 150, '1/3/2016'
UNION
SELECT 180, '1/4/2016'
UNION
SELECT 210, '1/5/2016'
UNION
SELECT 230, '1/6/2016'
UNION
SELECT 200, '1/7/2016'
UNION
SELECT 220, '1/8/2016'


INSERT INTO @projected_sales_data
SELECT 220, '1/8/2016' -- This data point matches the last actual sales number so that SSRS will draw a continuous line
UNION
SELECT 250, '1/9/2016'
UNION
SELECT 220, '1/10/2016'
UNION
SELECT 180, '1/11/2016'
UNION
SELECT 250, '1/12/2016'
UNION
SELECT 210, '1/13/2016'
UNION
SELECT 270, '1/14/2016'
UNION
SELECT 200, '1/15/2016'
UNION
SELECT 290, '1/16/2016'

SELECT actual_sales AS 'sales'
    , calendar_day AS 'calendar_day'
    , 'actual' AS 'sales_type'
FROM @actual_sales_data
UNION
SELECT projected_sales AS 'sales'
    , calendar_day AS 'calendar_day'
    , 'projected' AS 'sales_type'
FROM @projected_sales_data
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I'm able to do a continuous line, but I how do I place 2 legend labels at the bottom of the chart 1) Actual and 2) Projected?

Comment: From my example if you set the Chart's Value to 'sales', Category Group to 'calendar_day', and Series Group to 'sales_type' then you will get a legend that shows the difference between Projected and Actual sales.

Comment: If you need the 2 lines to be joined (note that every data point will appear, but they won't form a continuous line when data switches from actual to projected) then insert a  row into the projected data equal to the last actual sales amount with the same date.  This will overlay the projected and actual data on that data point and will draw a connected and continuous line.